# Can I change the command mode (: ...) so that I can have vi shortcuts?

Tags: regular-expression, command-line

Basically my question is this. On my terminal I have vi mode enable. It saves me lots of time editing command line arguments and zooming throught the file system. I would like to have a similar mode enabled in the vim command mode. Chief reason being is regular expressions for my code. s/ / / commands can get quite tedious and having a vi-like mode for editing commands would be awesome.

Also if this is not a recommended modifcation, does anyone have recommendations for plugins which make s/ / / usage more speedy and efficient?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can press `ctrl-f` after : to get access to the commands (same for /)

or you can enter cmd-mode with `q:`

Comment: You can change the default mapping of `<c-f>` by setting `'cedit'`. See `:h 'cedit'` for more help.